# "Etching" onto a cube

Tags: texturing, uv, height-map

Probably an elementary question, but could anyone give me a step-by-step method of taking a 2D map (representing carvings)and then "etching" or "engraving" the 2D picture onto the cube faces? Not just a simple map-wrap, but actually making it textured/bumped into the cube surface? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Steps for creating the below image:

1. take the default cube
2. add a subdivision surface modifier set to simple, with 7 levels
3. add a displacement modifier and choose your image texture, adjust strength so it doesnt displace it too much.

[image: result]

The actual engraving gets done with the displace, where you select Image Texture, and then use whatever image you want. However, displacement acts only on the existing geometry, so you need to make sure your mesh has enough detail to apply the texture to. To solve this, I have a subdivision surface set to simple (so it doesnt change the geometry) added before the displace:

[image: modifiers]

I hope this is what you're looking for.